# Mutate new columns based on values in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containg persons' id's and where they come from along with other columns

```
id Country x
1    usa   x1
2    uk    x2
3    usa   x3
4    che   x4
```

and another dataframe containing country codes and their income classification

```
Country income
usa     upper middle
uk      high
che     low
```

I want to create a new column in the first dataframe that lists country classification for each person such that I have:

```
id Country x   CountryIncome
1    usa   x1  upper middle
2    uk    x2  high
3    usa   x3  upper middle
4    che   x4  low
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: look at `dplyr::left_join()`

Comment: There's also base function `?merge`: `merge(df1, df2)` or `merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` solution would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data1 %>%
    left_join(data2, by = Country)
```

Answer (score 1):

standard `left_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "Country")
```